# SugarCRM installation frozen

Tags: php, mysql, installation, sugarcrm

I'm trying to install SugarCRM version 5.5.1. on a webhost.

Everything goes nice until the step when the installation begins.

The output is this one:

> Creating Sugar configuration file
> (config.php)
>
> Creating Sugar application tables,
> audit tables and relationship metadata
>
> .............

And never moves on!

I check the database and can see that there are tables missing. The install.log file doesnt have any errors, and the last line in the file is:

> 2010-04-27 22:17:03...creating
> Relationship Meta for Bug

It seems the installation stopped here, but i cant get why! Iv searched in the foruns, etc, but cant get it...

Anyone had this issue? Any clues about whats happening?

Thanks a lot

Comment: *(related)* http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/showthread.php?t=60044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this is caused by php timeout, please change your php.ini
max_execution_time = 600    ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds

Answer (score 0):

You could try and open source installer from: http://bitnami.org/